# Anime, Helicopter based sniper platform

Tags: story-identification, anime, androids

I can't remember the name of the anime, and I've looked at as much Ghost in the Shell as I can because I thought it was from that. But it's a scene where I think an android has taken hostages in this huge skyscraper and he's peering out from a window, and there is a police sniper helicopter that is miles away. It pans to the helicopter and the sniper has a gun platform secured to the roof and is using a special helmet to aim the gun. He fires, and the projectile is rocket-based and hits the hostage taker.

Then I think the scene ends up being revealed as a training mission or something.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry guys, I was wrong. It **is** from *Ghost in the Shell: SAC*, Ep. 15 "Machine Desirants", about two minutes in.

Thanks all the same

Answer (score 4):

TvTropes's [Improbable Aiming Skills](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ImprobableAimingSkills) has the following entry for Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha:

> Vice managed to snipe the head of a Combat Cyborg who was attacking an ally, with said ally being in the way of his line of sight, through a building window, from a moving helicopter that couldn't be seen from said building. And he did this while said cyborg had previously been playing possum, so he only had a split second to react and perform the shot.

I don't watch the series, but [this summary](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?512467-Where-I-Watch-Magical-Girl-Lyrical-Nanoha&s=c31aac743288345d98619b7fa2afeaee&p=12320174#post12320174) suggests it's Episode 24: Lightning.